# JavaScript get href onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to return the `href` attribute of a link using JavaScript when the user clicks on it. I want the URL the link is linking to displayed in an alert instead of loading the page.

I have the following code so far:

```
function doalert(){
    alert(document.getElementById("link").getAttribute("href"));
    return false;
}
```

With the following markup:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" id="link" onclick="return doalert()">Link</a>
```

For some reason, **no alert is ever displayed and the page loads instead.** Does anyone know why this is?

Using jQuery is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Seems to be the order of your code, try this

```
<script>
    function doalert(obj) {
        alert(obj.getAttribute("href"));
        return false;
    }
</script>
<a href="http://www.example.com/" id="link" onclick="doalert(this); return false;">Link</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YZ8yV/

http://jsfiddle.net/YZ8yV/2/

Comment: @akhil it is, but with script tags, highlighting there's no js code error

Comment: @kira it cancels the default navigation event - it will not subsequently try and navigate to `http://www.example.com/`

Comment: @jenson-button-event Thank you. Very clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

if you put an href in the link, it will just link to it, change the href attribute to data-link and then get that attribute and the js should work.