# Hide/Show multiple times on a page

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, I know that this question has been answered on this site numerous times and that is the main problem here. I am spoiled for choice in the answers and have been searching for a few hours, not finding anything directly similar. There must be plenty of ways to do this, but what I have right now is closest to what I want.

I have this for my code at the moment, for some reason the fiddle won't work, while it works fine in my code, must have missed something.

http://jsfiddle.net/PVLMX/

Html:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <p>This text is visible, but there is more.<a href="#" id="example-show"               class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;"><br/><br/>See more >></a>
    </p> 
    <div id="example" class="more">
        <p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below
            will hide this content again.</p>
        <p><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" 
            onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide this content >></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function showHide(shID) {
       if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
          if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
             document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
             document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
          }
          else {
             document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
             document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
          }
       }
    }
```

I need to be able to call the function for each new "Read More" on the page. At the moment, the first "See More" is always the target of the javascript, and I am not sure how to call this function for other links on the page.

Comment: Do you have some adversion to JQuery?  It's perfect for that kind of thing.

Comment: Tried all kinds of Jquery and just couldn't get it to work. Not even for a single "See more". It just comes down to the time limit I have and the fact that I am inexperienced with JQ.

Comment: Must you have seperate Show & Hide links? Can you live with a generic 'Show/Hide' link, i.e. one same link that makes it show and hide? That would make it so much easier to implement and manage.

Comment: @Fox you'll find you'll save _tons_ of time using JQuery... I'm guessing you're a novice Javascripter, and there's going to be a learning curve for anything, but you'll get returns on your investment in time quicker with JQuery than nearly anything else.

Comment: "Naw jQuery is for noobs... Learn Angular or Backbone." This conversation could go on and on....

Comment: try 
 onclick="showHide(this); return false;"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807929/javascript-get-href-onclick

Comment: @DanFarrell I will definitely learn JQuery when I get the chance, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTML, each id="" must be a unique identifier, you can't put two  id="example" so you need id="example" and id="example2" and so on.

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PVLMX/2/

```
<div id="wrap">
    <p>This text is visible, but there is more.<a href="#" id="example2-show"  
     class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example2');return false;"><br/><br/>See more >></a>
    </p> 
    <div id="example2" class="more">
        <p>This text was hidden, now you see it</p>
        <p><a href="#" id="example2-hide" class="hideLink" 
            onclick="showHide('example2');return false;">Hide this content >></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I changed:

1. every id="example.. to id="example2...  in the second div.
2. load the script in "No wrap - in head" mode (jsfiddle left option)

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle you need to select the `no wrap in <head>` option. Your code works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/uND9H/

Aslo you can't have duplicate id's

Answer (score 1):

if you want to generalise this, there is a much easier way in jquery  ie by using class you can bind click events and generalise them using class names. Here is an example , Check it out

```
    $('.showLink').bind('click',function(e){
      var obj = $(this).attr('id');

      var name = obj.replace("-show","-hidden");
      $('#'+name).css('display', 'inline-block'); 
    });

    $('.hideLink').bind('click',function(e){
      var obj = $(this).attr('id');
      var name = obj.replace("-hide","-hidden");
      $('#'+name).css('display', 'none'); 
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AmarnathRShenoy/AMf8y/

You can use class names multiple times and you must always remeber that id can never be duplicated

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it with jquery and much easier than you think

Jquery as follows:

```
$more = $('.more');

$('.showLink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $more.show();
})

$('.hideLink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $more.hide();
})
```

Also add a css style to display:none on .more class.
you can make it look a little nicer with slideToggle()

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/up36g/

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Unfortunately no JQuery I've used ever seems to work. I think I would rather wait until I understand some of it before using it.

Comment: You can also use CSS3 to do this. Might be less on the page load to use that but it wont work in antique browsers unless you use some polyfills

Comment: Here is a great course on jQuery to get you rolling
https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/