# Extract values from html tags using java with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

i m new using jsoup library (jsoup-1.14.3)

i have this html

```html
<html><head><title>Alfresco Content Repository</title><style>body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12pt; background-color: white; }
table { font-family: Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12pt; background-color: white; }
.listingTable { border: solid black 1px; }
.textCommand { font-family: verdana; font-size: 10pt; }
.textLocation { font-family: verdana; font-size: 11pt; font-weight: bold; color: #2a568f; }
.textData { font-family: verdana; font-size: 10pt; }
.tableHeading { font-family: verdana; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; color: white; background-color: #2a568f; }
.rowOdd { background-color: #eeeeee; }
.rowEven { background-color: #dddddd; }
</style></head>
<body>
<table cellspacing='2' cellpadding='3' border='0' width='100%'>
<tr><td colspan='4' class='textLocation'>Directory listing for /rep</td></tr>
<tr><td height='10' colspan='4'></td></tr></table><table cellspacing='2' cellpadding='3' border='0' width='100%' class='listingTable'>
<tr><td class='tableHeading' width='*'>Name</td><td class='tableHeading' width='10%'>Size</td><td class='tableHeading' width='20%'>Type</td><td class='tableHeading' width='25%'>Modified Date</td></tr>
<tr class='rowOdd'><td class='textData'><a href="/alfresco/webdav/rep/ED">ED</a></td><td class='textData'>&nbsp;</td><td class='textData'>&nbsp;</td><td class='textData'>Thu, 05 Jan 2017 11:11:14 GMT</td></tr>
<tr class='rowEven'><td class='textData'><a href="/alfresco/webdav/rep/FLOW%20CHART">FLOW CHART</a></td><td class='textData'>&nbsp;</td><td class='textData'>&nbsp;</td><td class='textData'>Thu, 27 Jun 2013 13:30:18 GMT</td></tr>
<tr class='rowOdd'><td class='textData'><a href="/alfresco/webdav/rep/file">file</a></td><td class='textData'>&nbsp;</td><td class='textData'>&nbsp;</td><td class='textData'>Wed, 10 Nov 2021 13:16:49 GMT</td></tr>


</table></body></html>
```

ANd , i'm trying to get the href of each  tag .

For example  ,

```html
  
<table cellspacing='2' cellpadding='3' border='0' width='100%'>
<tr><td colspan='4' class='textLocation'>Directory listing for /rep</td></tr>
<tr><td height='10' colspan='4'></td></tr></table><table cellspacing='2' cellpadding='3' border='0' width='100%' class='listingTable'>
<tr><td class='tableHeading' width='*'>Name</td><td class='tableHeading' width='10%'>Size</td><td class='tableHeading' width='20%'>Type</td><td class='tableHeading' width='25%'>Modified Date</td></tr>
<tr class='rowOdd'><td class='textData'><a href="/alfresco/webdav/rep/ED">ED</a></td><td class='textData'>&nbsp;</td><td class='textData'>&nbsp;</td><td class='textData'>Thu, 05 Jan 2017 11:11:14 GMT</td></tr>
```

I want to extract **"/alfresco/webdav/rep/ED"** and  **"ED"** and **"Thu, 05 Jan 2017 11:11:14 GMT"**

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807929/javascript-get-href-onclick/17808032) can help you for the `a` href. Also, you should get element, you can use lot of things such as `document.getElementById`

Comment: Do you want to extract all href values from all trs with class `textData` or all hrefs all together, the answer will depend on which hrefs you want to select and it's not clear from the question

Comment: @AntonBelev , yes all  hrefs

Comment: There are three tags with the attribute `href`. Why don't you handle all three? `Thu, 05 Jan 2017 11:11:14 GMT` has nothing to do with the attribute `href`. How do you identify it?

Comment: @Elikill58 this solution is for javaScript , i want to get a solution with java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to parse the html which is String to Document.

```
final Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Then you need to select all `tr` tags which contains `a` tag.

```
final Elements trElements = document.select("tr:has(a)");
```

After, you need to browse each `tr` tag found :

```
for (final Element trElement : trElements) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

For each tr tag, you retrieve the `href` value of tag. But first, you need to retrieve the `a` tag :

```
final Element aElement = trElement.select("a").first();
```

Then, we retrieve, the value of `href` attribute in tag `a`.

```
final String href = aElement.attr("href");
```

For name, you retrieve the text content of `a` tag :

```
final String name = aElement.text();
```

For date, you need to retrieve the fourth `td` tag from `tr` tag :

```
final Element dateTdElement = trElement.select("td").get(3);
```

And just retrieve the value text to get the date content :

```
final String date = dateTdElement.text();
```

**NB** : The method `select()` accept a css query. All css query is valid with extended syntax like ':has()' and other part. See Jsoup documention for more detail.

To resume all in one code :

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String html = "<html><head><title>Alfresco Content Repository</title><style>body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12pt; background-color: white; }\n" +
            "table { font-family: Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12pt; background-color: white; }\n" +
            ".listingTable { border: solid black 1px; }\n" +
            ".textCommand { font-family: verdana; font-size: 10pt; }\n" +
            ".textLocation { font-family: verdana; font-size: 11pt; font-weight: bold; color: #2a568f; }\n" +
            ".textData { font-family: verdana; font-size: 10pt; }\n" +
            ".tableHeading { font-family: verdana; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; color: white; background-color: #2a568f; }\n" +
            ".rowOdd { background-color: #eeeeee; }\n" +
            ".rowEven { background-color: #dddddd; }\n" +
            "</style></head>\n" +
            "<body>\n" +
            "<table cellspacing='2' cellpadding='3' border='0' width='100%'>\n" +
            "<tr><td colspan='4' class='textLocation'>Directory listing for /rep</td></tr>\n" +
            "<tr><td height='10' colspan='4'></td></tr></table><table cellspacing='2' cellpadding='3' border='0' width='100%' class='listingTable'>\n" +
            "<tr><td class='tableHeading' width='*'>Name</td><td class='tableHeading' width='10%'>Size</td><td class='tableHeading' width='20%'>Type</td><td class='tableHeading' width='25%'>Modified Date</td></tr>\n" +
            "<tr class='rowOdd'><td class='textData'><a href=\"/alfresco/webdav/rep/ED\">ED</a></td><td class='textData'>&nbsp;</td><td class='textData'>&nbsp;</td><td class='textData'>Thu, 05 Jan 2017 11:11:14 GMT</td></tr>\n" +
            "<tr class='rowEven'><td class='textData'><a href=\"/alfresco/webdav/rep/FLOW%20CHART\">FLOW CHART</a></td><td class='textData'>&nbsp;</td><td class='textData'>&nbsp;</td><td class='textData'>Thu, 27 Jun 2013 13:30:18 GMT</td></tr>\n" +
            "<tr class='rowOdd'><td class='textData'><a href=\"/alfresco/webdav/rep/file\">file</a></td><td class='textData'>&nbsp;</td><td class='textData'>&nbsp;</td><td class='textData'>Wed, 10 Nov 2021 13:16:49 GMT</td></tr>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "</table></body></html>";

    final Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    final Elements trElements = document.select("tr:has(a)");
    for (final Element trElement : trElements) {
        final Element aElement = trElement.select("a").first();
        final String href = aElement.attr("href");
        System.out.println("Href : " + href);

        final String name = aElement.text();
        System.out.println("Name : " + name);

        final Element dateTdElement = trElement.select("td").get(3);
        final String date = dateTdElement.text();
        System.out.println("Date : " + date);
    }
}
```

It prints something like :

```
Href : /alfresco/webdav/rep/ED
Name : ED
Date : Thu, 05 Jan 2017 11:11:14 GMT
Href : /alfresco/webdav/rep/FLOW%20CHART
Name : FLOW CHART
Date : Thu, 27 Jun 2013 13:30:18 GMT
Href : /alfresco/webdav/rep/file
Name : file
Date : Wed, 10 Nov 2021 13:16:49 GMT
```